# Defining apt questions inside the Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, apt

I am trying to create a Dockerfile to install postfix, but the installation asks this question:

```
Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your needs.

 No configuration:
  Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.
 Internet site:
  Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.
 Internet with smarthost:
  Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such
  as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.
 Satellite system:
  All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for delivery.
 Local only:
  The only delivered mail is the mail for local users. There is no network.

  1. No configuration  3. Internet with smarthost  5. Local only
  2. Internet Site     4. Satellite system
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

MAINTAINER xxx

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y postfix postfix-mysql dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-mysql mariadb-server\
 && apt-get clean
```

How can I provide answers to the installation of Postfix non interactively?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change RUN instruction in you Dockerfile:

```
 RUN apt-get update\
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y postfix postfix-mysql dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-mysql mariadb-server\
 && apt-get clean
```

Or better solution can be:

Add this instruction in you Dockerfile `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`
(it is only available during build).